# Why my code to plot is not showing the output with the titles, xlabel and ylabel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I have tried to plot a barplot using `matplotlib`, but when I wrote the code to show the title and xlabel-ylabel, they are not shown. What am I doing wrong?

I have created a data frame and tried to plot the same using `df.plot(...)`.
But then I did not get the label option and xticks. That is why I tried this.

```
# Make a fake dataset:
districts = ['Alappuzha','Ernakulam','Idukki','Kannur','Kasaragod','Kollam','Kottayam','Kozhikode','Malappuram','Palakkad','Pathanamthitta','Thiruvananthapuram','Wayanad','Thrissur']
distAb = ['Alp','Ern','Idk','Knr','Ksd','Klm','Ktm','Kzd','Mlp','Plk','Pta','Tvm','Wyd','Tsr']
population = [2121943,3279860,1107453,2525637,1302600,2629703,1979384,3089543,4110956,2810892,1195537,3307284,816558,3110327]
posArrange = np.arange(len(districts))
```

## Create bars

```
plt.bar(posArrange,population,color='#ff9900', width=.8)


plt.title='Population of Districts in Kerala'
plt.xlabel='Districts'
plt.ylabel='Population'
plt.xticks(posArrange,distAb)
```

## Show graphic

```
plt.show()
```

The output is not what I expected. It did not show the xlabel, ylabel and the title.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffa5U.png)

Comment: `plt.title` is a function. You need to *call* it. `plt.title("My title")`

Comment: i tried that as well just now.. but shows up error

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Sure, because at the moment you assigned a string to it, it's not a function any more.

Comment: i re run the cells again from import matplotlib.pyplot as plt onwards. but same error

Comment: Try restarting your kernel and then try the code.

Comment: Yes, you have destroyed those functions. You need to restart python.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.. worked out well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title`, `xlabel`, `ylabel`, and `xticks` are functions which means that they are followed by brackets with arguments.
Change the following lines accordingly and you should see the desired elements in your plot.

```
plt.title('Population of Districts in Kerala')
plt.xlabel('Districts')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.xticks(posArrange,distAb)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i have reassigned to string.. I tried to restart the kernal of my google.colab but still the error shows up... TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I can confirm the results from Arienrhod. If you still get the 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable' Error message, then your environment has not properly been set back. Try checking this by outputting the variable ´plt.title´. If it returns you 'Population of Districts on Kerala', then you have not made an actual restart of the kernel.
After a proper kernel restart, if you call for plt.title it should return something like <function matplotlib.pyplot.title>

Answer (score 2):

I have used below code in my project and it's working. You can use same like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
left = [1, 2, 3, 4]
height = [logistic_score*100,naive_score*100,svm_score*100,mlp_score*100] 
tick_label = ['Logistic Regression', 'Naive Bayes', 'SVM', 'Multi linear 
perceptron'] 
plt.bar(left, height, tick_label = tick_label, width = 0.3, color = ['red', 
'green','blue','violet'])
plt.xlabel('Algorithms')
plt.ylabel('Efficiency')
plt.title('Results Comaprision') 
plt.show()
```